# LEFT JOIN - narrow things down

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I'm currently having a problem with a legacy app I just inherited on my new job. I have a SQL query that's way too long to respond and I need to find a way to fasten it.
This query acts on 3 tables:

- SESSION contains all users visits
- CONTACT contains all the messages people have been sending through a form and contains a "session_id" field that links back to the SESSION id field
- ACCOUNT contains users accounts (people who registered on the website) and whose "id" field is linked back in SESSION (through a "SESSION.account_id" field). ACCOUNT and CONTACT are no linked in any way, besides the SESSION table (legacy app...).

I can't change this structure unfortunately.

My query tries to recover ALL the interesting sessions to serve to the administrator. I need to find all sessions that links back to an account OR a contact form.

Currently, the query is structured like that :

```
SELECT s.id
/*  a few fields from ACCOUNT and CONTACT tables */

FROM session s
LEFT JOIN account act ON act.id = s.account_id
LEFT JOIN contact c on c.session_id = s.id
WHERE s.programme_id = :program_id
AND (
c.id IS NOT NULL
OR
act.id IS NOT NULL
)
```

Problem is, the SESSION table is growing pretty fast (as you can expect) and with 400k records it slows things down for some programs ( :programme_id in the query).

I tried to use an UNION query with two INNER JOIN query, one between SESSION and ACCOUNT and the other one between SESSION and CONTACT, but it doesn't give me the same number of records and I don't really understand why.

Can somebody help me to find a better way to make this query ?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I think you just need indexes.  For this query:

```
SELECT s.id
/*  a few fields from ACCOUNT and CONTACT tables */

FROM session s LEFT JOIN
     account act
     ON act.id = s.account_id LEFT JOIN
     contact c 
     ON c.session_id = s.id
WHERE s.programme_id = :program_id AND
      (c.id IS NOT NULL OR act.id IS NOT NULL);
```

You want indexes on `session(programme_id, account_id, id)`, `account(id)` and `contact(session_id)`.

It is important that `programme_id` be the first column in the index on `session`.

Comment: Oh my god i'm a moron, thanks a lot. I actually thought about indexes but I was too busy trying to optimize this query. My query went from 30s to 0.02s !

Answer (score 0):

@Gordon already suggested you add an index, which is generally the easy and effective solution, so I'm going to answer a different part of your question.

> I tried to use an UNION query with two INNER JOIN query, one between
>   SESSION and ACCOUNT and the other one between SESSION and CONTACT, but
>   it doesn't give me the same number of records and I don't really
>   understand why.

That part is rather simple: the `JOIN` returns a result set that contains the rows of both tables joined together. So in the first case you would end up with a result that looks like

```
session.id, session.column2, session.column3, ..., account.id, account.column2, account.column3, ....
```

and a second where

```
session.id, session.column2, session.column3, ..., contact.id, contact.column2, contact.column3, ....
```

Then an `UNION` will faill unless the `contact` and `account` tables have the same number of columns with correspoding types, which is unlikely. Otherwise, the database will be unable to perform a `UNION`. [From the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html) (emphasis mine):

> The column names from the first SELECT statement are used as the column names for the results returned. **Selected columns listed in corresponding positions of each SELECT statement should have the same data type.** (For example, the first column selected by the first statement should have the same type as the first column selected by the other statements.)

Just perform both `INNER JOIN`s seperately and compare the results if you're unsure.

If you want to stick to an `UNION` solution, make sure to perform a `SELECT` only on corresponding columns : doing `SELECT s.id` would be trivial but it should work, for instance.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I appreciate it. In my test I added some NULL fields in each query to match the number of fields, so it might have been this trick that made my query fails.